# How to convert Javascript object to JSVal

Tags: haskell, ghcjs

I'm working on my first GHCJS web application with Miso but I'm stuck on how to convert an GHCJS `Object` type into a `JSVal` to further use it. I can't find anything at all on how to do this...

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Object` is [this Object](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghcjs-base-0.2.0.0/docs/JavaScript-Object.html#t:Object) then it's an instance of `IsJSVal` which [defines](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghcjs-base-0.2.0.0/docs/GHCJS-Types.html#t:IsJSVal):

```
jsval :: IsJSVal a => a -> JSVal
```